# Can some explain for the boolean duplicateds method in this code?

Tags: java, user-interface

The code which under of this is done already
but I cant understand the function of the boolean duplicatecharacters
why the I !=... and what is the  str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i),
appreciated if you explain for me.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class SimplApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
     //JTextField
    static JTextField t;

    // JFrame
    static JFrame f;

    // JButton
    static JButton b;

    // label to display text
    static JLabel l;

    // default constructor
    SimplApp() {

    }

    static boolean duplicatecharacters(String str)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            if(i!=(str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i))))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // main class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create a new frame to store text field and button
        f = new JFrame("textfield");

        // create a label to display text
        l = new JLabel("nothing entered");

        // create a new button
        b = new JButton("submit");

        // create a object of the text class
        SimplApp te = new SimplApp();

        // addActionListener to button
        b.addActionListener(te);

        // create a object of JTextField with 16 columns
        t = new JTextField(16);

        // create a panel to add buttons and textfield
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        // add buttons and textfield to panel
        p.add(t);
        p.add(b);
        p.add(l);

        // add panel to frame
        f.add(p);

        // set the size of frame
        f.setSize(300, 300);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    // if the button is pressed
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String s = e.getActionCommand();
        if (s.equals("submit")) {
            boolean b=SimplApp.duplicatecharacters(t.getText());
            // set the text of the label to the text of the field
            if(b==true)
                l.setText("It has duplicates");
            else
                l.setText("It doesn't have duplicates");

            // set the text of field to blank
            //t.setText(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

So I just want to know how is the function work,  why they write the function by using != since the function is use to find the duplicate input
shouldnt it be like if the string.length is 4,
and use the for looping search down 1 by 1 and if one of the number equal to another number then return true
below these words are just to fill the words number hehe

Comment: nothing to do with javascript

Comment: String method `lastIndexOf` returns the _last_ index of a given character (the closest to the string end), for example for string `"abca"` when you check a character at index 0 `a`, this method returns 3, thus `0 != 3` is true and it means that a character `a` is duplicated.  For `b` at the index 1, the `lastIndexOf` also returns 1 -- then this character is not duplicated.

Comment: So (str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i))) will note down the index number and char of the character which first appear, such as the A has first appeared at index 3, so A for now  can represent as index 3 and also its A. By the way, does the meaning of " i" is no just for counting the length, it also can represent as the index and the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function checks the String for duplicated chars. For example, let's say we hava a string like

```
String str = "abcdaf"
```

the for loop iterate over the length of the string. Indexes ->

```
0 -> a
1 -> b
2 -> c
3 -> d
4 -> a
5 -> f
```

So, when iterating the function is checking like this ->

```
if(i != str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i)))
```

let's take index 0.

```
// str = "abcdaf"
str.charAt(0) // returns 'a'
str.lastIndexOf('a') // returns 4
```

0 != 4 means that there is more than one 'a' in a string.

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!got it!!!!thank youuuu hahahaha